# Change the position of a list item when clicked

Tags: javascript

On what algorithm can solve the following problem? I need to when you click on one of the menu block received class active and got up in the middle.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li class="active">4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
}

.active {
    background: orange;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wh9mfbqh/)

Comment: middle of which element

Comment: What you would do is... copy the html of the ul, edit the html and then attach it back the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding the active class do the below

```
var liElems = document.getElementsByTagName('li'), mid = Math.floor(liElems.length/2);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElems, function (item, idx) {
    item.idx = idx;
    item.onclick = function () {
        document.querySelector('li.active').classList.remove('active');
        this.classList.add('active');
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ep295qL1/1)

---

```
var liElems = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    length = liElems.length,
    mid = Math.floor(liElems.length / 2);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElems, function (item, idx) {
    item.idx = idx;
    item.onclick = function () {
        document.querySelector('li.active').classList.remove('active');
        this.classList.add('active');


        if (liElems[mid].idx != mid) {
            if (liElems[mid].idx == length - 1) {
                this.parentNode.appendChild(liElems[mid])
            } else {
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(liElems[mid], liElems[liElems[mid].idx])
            }
        }

        var pos = mid < this.idx ? mid : mid + 1;
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, liElems[pos])

    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ep295qL1)